# iphone, How can I get rid of this potential leak, caused by using return after UIAlertview?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uialertview

Heres my analyzer leak...

[image]

I need to return and stop execution of the rest of my method, as I'm stopping the user as hes enter some text fields incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By line 442 I'm guessing that that is the `alert` value that you set after the WarningMessage. Notice that you've not released it. After the `show` try:

```
[alert show];
[alert autorelease];
return;
```

Comment: You can safely release (not only autorelease) the alert after showing it. This is even the better solution, as the object gets deallocated immediately, because its retain count reaches 0 at this point. You get the memory back immediately.